# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'

Tags: android, google-app-engine, dependencies, server, build.gradle

I added some new library to 'libs', and then when I tried to compile the file via the gradle file it showed me the error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   I am adding the build.gradle code (it's the gradle of the servlet using Google App Engine server).
>   I saw few similar questions in the past but none of the solutions fixed my problem.

```
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.14'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:1.11.0-beta'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.13.1-beta'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can track down what the error was. Any details?

Comment: I fixed it. The problem with in the other gradle.build file (of the app and not of the server). I added some unnecessary compile statment .

Comment: @davidmoshko What do you mean gradle file of the server??